# Configuration to allow more BPEL throughput

Tags: bpel, throughput, open-esb

We are experiencing a throughput blocking issue. We are submitting requests to
a controlling BPEL process that at the beginning has a "Receive" and a "Reply"
activity. The controlling BPEL then orchestrates more web services with Invoke
activities. The problem is we can only get about 7 of these top level processes
started. As subordinate BPEL processes complete the top level "Receives"
continue to respond, so everything completes. We control how many top level
processes we want to invoke, but we need to understand how to control the
limiting factor so we can increase or decrease calls to the top level process.

Each top level BPEL process is waiting on an invocation of one other BPEL
process that has invoked a web-service to do work. All other Invokes have
completed.

Environement: OpenESB 2.3 running on glassfish server (using jdk1.7.0_51).
Number of cpus:          grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo            24

Memory:   $ free -m
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          23932        8481        2771          91       12679       14943
Swap:         15259          21       15238

Settings that are documented that we have tried:
No setting has impacted the behavior of only starting 7 with blocking
on the 8th request.

JVM memory settings
-XX:PermSize=7168m
-XX:MaxPermSize=7168m
-Xmx8192m

sun-bpel-engine configuration
Number of Threads: tried 24 tried 80 original value was 10

sun-http-binding Configuration
Number of Outbound Threads: 500  was 10

Http Service:
RequestProcessing
Thread Count:  500    was 128

Connection Pool
Max Pending Count:    4096    Maximum number of pending connections on the
listen socket
Queue Size:           4096    Bytes
Receive Buffer Size:  4096    Bytes
Send Buffer Size:     8192    Bytes

Casa QOS endpoint editing
maximumConcurrencyLimit="300"